# In the example below, textit{} doesn't work. What could I use instead.?

Tags: beamer, theorems

I inherited the \setbeamertemplate code below and I like the font that it generates , but \textit doesn't work. What should I use instead?
 (I don't know exactly what the code means, can you refer me to documentation?  Also, as the output indicates, can I generate a header (blue) without the white bar appearing?

```latex
\documentclass[ aspectratio = 1610 ]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{% 
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
{  \inserttheoremheadfont  
 \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else \inserttheoremaddition\fi% 
}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame} 
 \begin{definition} [ {  How do I get this \textit{text  to appear in standard italics} ? }  \\
 ]
 \end{definition}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look in your `.log` file, you'll see

```latex
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 19.
```

This means that the font family lacks a bold italic font.

Add `\usepackage{lmodern}`, but also fix your code.

```latex
\documentclass[ aspectratio = 1610 ]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}%
  {\inserttheoremheadfont\ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\inserttheoremaddition\fi}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[How do I get this \textit{text to appear in standard italics}?]
Some text
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Spaces are significant in almost all places.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks.  Is the other question clear. I  would like to write

Comment: \begin{definition}[How do I get this \textit{text to appear in standard italics}?]                      \end{definition}                                                                                                                      and get just the blue bar without the white stuff underneath:  That's because some of my definitions don't require   any additional text.